# Wordpress: Remove link #id for read more

Tags: php, wordpress

When we do looping in wordpress, and the content has `<!--more-->` wordpress will cut the content in frontend view  and give us link like "read more"

An example link of readmore: `http://domain.com/foo/#204`.

How do I remove the part of `#204`?

Comment: yes it is `<a href="http://domain.com/foo/#204">read more</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your code

```
Before
$output .= ' <a href="'. get_permalink() . "#more-$id\" class=\"more-link\">$more_link_text</a>";

After

$output .= ' <a href="'. get_permalink() ."\" class=\"more-link\">$more_link_text</a>";
```

Or this plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-link-modifier/

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-anchor-link-from-read-more-link

Comment: Thank you, this plugin work like charm. all of my problem is solved. many thank :)